# Is it possible to change split values manually in a decison tree classifier created through sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, decision-tree

Suppose, I create a decision tree classifier through sklearn library.Now,I tried to see what are the split values inside the tree with this function: export_text()

```
|--- feature1<= 1.50

|   |--- feature2<= 0.88
|   |   |--- feature3<= 0.05
|   |   |   |--- feat4<= 0.58
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 1.0
|   |   |   |--- feat4>  0.58
|   |   |   |   |--- class: 1.0
|   |   |--- feat3>  0.05
|   |   |   |--- class: 1.0
|   |--- feat2>  0.88
|   |   |--- class: 0.0
|--- feat1>  1.50
|   |--- feat5<= 0.22
|   |   |--- feat6<= 0.90
|   |   |   |--- feat7<= 0.1
|   |   |   |   |   |--- other_chars >  0.14
|   |   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 0.0
|   |   |--- feat3>  0.90
|   |   |   |--- feat5<= 0.13
|   |   |   |   |--- feat6<= 0.25
|   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 1.0
|   |   |   |   |--- feat6>  0.25
|   |   |   |   |   |--- class: 0.0
```

Now, is it possible to change these feature's split values iterating through the tree manually?
like, at first split, we  have feature1 as split feature and its value is 1.5

What my requirement is, once we reach that feature1 split point, I want to change the value from 1.5 to say, 1.2 and then save the tree into pickle file and use that for future predictions.

Comment: Yes possible, but what do you mean by "manually"? What is your end goal?

Comment: manually in the sense, if a tree created on a dataset1, and now I have dataset2, I just want to  set  values at split points for tree(created on dataset1) based on dataset2.
for eg: when i go to root node of tree, I have feature1, so,i will calculate split value for dataset2 based on feature1(either gini or entropy) and then change feature1 value in that tree. and similarly it should happen for all  nodes in that tree

Comment: finally, store this tree in a pickle file and use for next predictions.

Comment: This admittedly is lot more complicated than what I thought. Check [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html). And I suggest you clarify these details in question